# Can a non-California private resident transfer a handgun (used) not on the DOJ roster to a California resident? If so,what would the procedure be?

Tags: california, firearms

I have a friend in Oregon who has some 1911 frames that i would like to buy from him.  Is this possible with me being a California resident.  Also, can a non-California resident, who will be relocating to California, bring into California his handguns if they are not on the Californian roster?